# I am using jquery-1.2.6.js in my application, still not able to use live method

Tags: javascript

```
C#


foreach (DataRow Row in oDs.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    LitPreferances.Text += "<Li ID=LI_" + Row["pk_Preference_Branch_ID"].ToString() +"_"+ Row["pk_Preference_BranchType_ID"].ToString() +">" + Row["Branch_Name"].ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' title='delete' class='itemDelete' onclick='return RemoveBranch();' tooltip='Remove Branch'>Remove</a></Li>";
                }

Javascript

 function RemoveBranch() {
   $('.itemDelete').live('click', function () {
     $(this).closest('Li').remove();
   });

   return false;
 }
```

When I am using live for above method, it's showing error as object doesn't support property or method 'live'.

Comment: Why do you have `.live()` inside a function? That would be an odd place for it. Do you understand what `.live()` does?

Comment: Actually i have created a dynamic button on server side and on click on that button i am removing some stuff. U can check in my Edit post

Comment: The working of Live is , Its used like an selector where i want to remove that particular li which is just clicked

Comment: No, that's not what `.live()` is for. The `.live()` method is for assigning an event handler to the `document` to handle all clicks on elements that match the provided selector. You already have an event handler bound to the element itself via `onclick="..."`. Please read [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

`live` function  is available in version 1.3+.

**Reference**

https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thanx but can i use any thing else instead live

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408929/how-to-mimic-jquery-live-or-use-2-jquery-versions-in-the-presence-of-a-protot

Answer (score 0):

`live` was only added on version 1.3, deprecated by version 1.7, and removed by version 1.9. See https://api.jquery.com/live/,